# Java: How do you return multiple objects in order?

Tags: java, return, multiple-instances

I am trying to get an intelligent agent to turn right 3 times. Since you cannot return multiple objects, how can I call `this.buildPhysicalAction(TurnRightAction.class)` 3 times in a row?

```
public class VacuumWorldExplorerMind extends VacuumWorldDefaultMind {

  @Override
  public EnvironmentalAction decide(Object... parameters) {

    PerceiveAction range = new PerceiveAction();
    VacuumWorldCoordinates currentLocation;

    this.buildPhysicalAction(TurnRightAction.class);
    this.buildPhysicalAction(TurnRightAction.class);
    this.buildPhysicalAction(TurnRightAction.class);

    while (true) {

      // if perceive range-checkForWall == 1
      // turn left
      // count steps made = stepsMade
      if (range.getPerceptionRange() == 1) {
        return this.buildPhysicalAction(TurnLeftAction.class);
      }

      return this.buildPhysicalAction(MoveAction.class);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can return an array, which can contain multiple values.

Comment: How can I add this.buildPhysicalAction(TurnRightAction.class) to an array though? Do you mean ArrayList?

Comment: Slighlty unrelated, but might I ask what the point of the `while (true)` loop is? The code allways returns on its first iteration, so that loop seems kind of pointless

Comment: yeah you're right, I'll remove it

Comment: An ArrayList seems like a good choice for your needs, since it preserves an order which is important in this case I bet. Additionally you can make use of Composite pattern, which will let you composing environmantal actions, and provide a good abstraction for the consumer, which in turn will simply call some Execute method on your Action and it will propagate the execution further on to inner actions.

Comment: That's a great idea, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a design choice.
One approach could be to define classes like : TurnRightAction, TurnRight**Twice**Action and TurnRight**Thrice**Action and call them respectively when you need to turn once, twice or thrice.

Another choice is what you are already doing, call TurnRightAction number of times the action is required.

Comment: calling this.buildPhysicalAction(TurnRightAction.class); alone will not turn right, I need to return this.buildPhysicalAction(TurnRightAction.class);

Comment: So u can return TurnRightThriceAction for 3 times turning right. Another way would be to return wrapper class containing this.buildPhysicalAction(TurnRightAction.class) and count.